How do I make cors policy on hapi.js working?
I have this hapi.js restful api server demo that tried to be accessed by external domain but failed. here is the Hapi instance:
const init = async () => {
  const server = Hapi.server({
    port: 5000,
    host: 'localhost',
    routes: {
      cors: {
        origin: ['*'],
      },
    },
  });

  server.route(routes);

  await server.start();
  console.log(`Server running on port ${server.info.uri}`);
};

What could be the problem?
I tried to access it from external domain. I tried to modify my browser security, checked for mixed content, and even modify my macos network setting include disabling firewalls, etc. but this error kept coming:
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/notes' from origin 'http://notesapp-v1.dicodingacademy.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`.Understand this errorAI
abe5c84d8f779a0d6876d1a20ed7bd32e2302c43.3c745b2819eb12ef4f8b.js:1 
        
        
POST http://localhost:5000/notes net::ERR_FAILED

